# Capybara tests don't work, while actual app works fine. React front-end in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

**Specs**: Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5.1, Yarn 1.91.1, React-Rails 2.6.0, selenium-webdriver 3.14, chromedriver 77, capybara gem 3.29 , Ubuntu 18.04

**Issue**: I created a questionnaire using react components in a Rails app which works when run in development mode.  I can click the yes or no button then a callback function renders the new question text.  However my selenium integration tests don't pick this up.  The `page` object continues to have the same text for the first question so I receive an error like this

`Failure/Error: expect(question.text).to include('last question')
 expected "first question" to include "last question"`

The test itself looks like this in features/questionnaire.rb

```
 RSpec.feature "Onboarding Questionnaire", type: :feature, js:true do
 (...)
 it...
   question = find('h3.question')
   expect(question.text).to include('first question')
   yes = find('#yes')
   yes.click
   sleep 5
   question = find('h3.question')
   expect(question.text).to include('last question')
```

The problem arises after `yes.click`.  I thought at first my animations were causing the issue, but I removed those and it is just using setState in my callback function.

Here is my react callback function

```
 saveAnswer(e) {
    questionnaire = this
    ++questionnaire.state.page
    questionnaire.setState({page: questionnaire.state.page})
  }
```

Here is my driver config
     `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now using `sleep` works as desired.  Here are the changes I made.

1) I removed the deprecated gem `chromedriver-helper` and replaced it with `webdrivers`

2) Added `require 'webdrivers'` to the rails_helper.rb file.

3) Found error in my react code (which wasn't showing up in development or being logged in chrome webdriver) of `questionnaire = this` which I changed to `var questionnaire = this`.

Integration tests now pass fine using `selenium_chrome_headless`